# EntityReference can have no more than one related object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two identical controller actions and two nearly identical views (one just has a different javscript file with it). One view works just fine, but the other gets hung up on this EF error:

```
A relationship multiplicity constraint violation occurred: An EntityReference can have no more than one related object, but the query returned more than one related object. This is a non-recoverable error.
```

I understand the error but it doesn't make any sense in the context, especially when one view works and one doesn't. Here is bit from the two views which is causing it to choke (it's nasty but lets ignore that for now...):

```
<% var x = ((IEnumerable<Project.Models.Booth>)ViewData["booths"]).Where(b => b.RowNumber == i && b.ColumnNumber == j && b.BoothGroupID == item.ID).FirstOrDefault(); %>

                        <%if ( x != null)
                          { %>
                            <td class="assigned" title="<%: x.BoothNumber %> - <%: x.Exhibitor.Name %>" style="width:<%: item.Width %>px; height:<%: item.Height %>px;"></td>
                        <%}
                          else
                          { %>
                            <td style="width:<%: item.Width %>px; height:<%: item.Height %>px;"></td>
                        <%} %>
```

This is the controller action for the details view which causes the exception:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var results = from g in db.BoothGroups
                      where g.PlanID == id
                      select g;

        ViewData["id"] = id;

        var plan = (from p in db.Plans
                    where p.ID == id
                    select p).FirstOrDefault();

        ViewData["imagePath"] = "/plans/" + plan.Name.ToString().Replace(" ", "").ToLower() + "/" + plan.ImageFileName;

        var booths = from b in db.Booths
                     where b.PlanID == id
                     select b;

        ViewData["booths"] = booths;

        return View(results);
    }
```

This is the controller action for the one that works, there is an extra call to populate a drop down list from viewdata, but I removing it doesn't seem to affect one view or the other.

```
public ActionResult EditAssignment(int id)
    {
        var results = from g in db.BoothGroups
                      where g.PlanID == id
                      select g;

        ViewData["id"] = id;

        var plan = (from p in db.Plans
                    where p.ID == id
                    select p).FirstOrDefault();

        ViewData["imagePath"] = "/plans/" + plan.Name.ToString().Replace(" ", "").ToLower() + "/" + plan.ImageFileName;

        var exhibitors = from e in db.Exhibitors
                         where e.MeetingCode == plan.MeetingCode
                         orderby e.Name
                         select e;

        ViewData["exhibitors"] = new SelectList(exhibitors, "ID", "Name");

        var booths = from b in db.Booths
                     where b.PlanID == id
                     select b;

        ViewData["booths"] = booths;

        return View(results);
    }
```

I'm rather stumped by this, any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a standard EDMX / generated classes or something else?

Introducing a strongly-typed view and putting all the code to populate a view model for it into the controller might help you pinpoint where the error is occurring.

Comment: You need to look at the generated SQL and its DB results. The error suggests there's a problem with your model, or DB, or both.

Comment: @Hightechrider It's generated, but modified after the fact to include a view, I added a relation to link the view with a db table.

@Craig I can get through the results set in one view just fine, in the other however it's null, which is odd since it's the same query.

Comment: And presumably there is a relationship between Exhibitors and Booths?  So when you load Exhibitors you are loading Booth references too which then conflict somehow with the view you've added?  Sounds like the edits you made to the EDMX are the cause of the problem here but without seeing the EDMX itself it would be hard to say exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error doesn't seem to indicate this problem, but I think you should enumerate your queries first and see what happens.

```
var results = (from g in db.BoothGroups
              where g.PlanID == id
              select g).ToList();
```

and

```
var booths = (from b in db.Booths
             where b.PlanID == id
             select b).ToList();
```

as it is, you are passing an `ObjectQuery` to your view and which can cause problems with  view rendering since the `ObjectContext` may not be in the state it was in when you made the query. Also check you model objects and make sure they are not calling the db from within somewhere.

Comment: Definitely use ToList() on Linq queries and definitely have your views strongly type to System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<BoothGroup>> (example).